# how can i get html code using preg_match in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I am testing my simple php code.

```
<?php

$subject = '<table class="data-tb" summary="blablalba.">';
$regex = '/<table[^>]*>/';
preg_match($regex, $subject, $match).
print_r($match);

?>
```

i want the result is same with $subject.
but i can't get anything from the result. nothing is in $match.

it works fine when i'm not using
'<' and '>' in $regex. but i want this two signs are also included in the result.
i already tried using '\' to escape '<', '>'. but it doesn not works.

how can i solve it?

Comment: `nothing is in $match` => sure?: https://3v4l.org/edb5A https://regex101.com/r/ukDJfs/1

Comment: yes. but when i delete '<' in $regex, there is a result in $match and the reslut is same with subject just except '<'

Comment: I dont get it. If you delete '<' the match is still there. Just without the starting < of course.

Comment: You do not not get a match - you get `<table class="data-tb" summary="blablalba.">`, but you of course don’t _see_ that when you output it in an HTML context. Use something like `echo htmlspecialchars(var_export($match, 1));`

Comment: To Xatenev. Array([0] => )  << this is exactly all that i can see in my result page when i run my test php file above. :(

Comment: and the result is same with your second comment when i delete '<'

Comment: To CBroe. really thanks. it works. :)